# changing styles of element(s) , not based on firing event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm learning react and I'm editing a tutorial Tic Tac Toe game. When there is a winner, the winning line should be highlighted. I passed a `line` prop all the way down to the `Square` component and i came up with this code:

```
function Square(props) {
    props.line ? 
       return (
          <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick} style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>
            {props.value}
          </button>
       );
    :
       return (
          <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.value}
          </button>
       );
}
```

First, there is a syntax error at first `return`, but whenever i try to fix it, i just create a new one, clearly i don't know how to handle JavaScript inside `return`, then even if what i intended was a correct syntax, it probably still would change only the color of a particular `Square` and not the whole `props.line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the style in one return statement, use this:

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick} style={props.line ? {backgroundColor: "red"} : undefined}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}
```

You can take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/ahmetemrekilinc/pen/LYmyErO?editors=0011) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: that doesn't account for style change.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer with the style check.

Comment: thanks for that, though as expected it changes styles of all the squares, not just those in the `line`, which obviously is not your fault as you can't see the rest of the code. i did something similar, but one component higher, checking for `this.props.line ?` as you did, but also for `this.props.line.includes(/* the square to be rendered */)`.